# How to debug in Ecllipse IDE? Java library file are being opened while crossing though the functions and return statements

Tags: java, debugging

How to debug in Eclipse IDE? Java library file are being opened while crossing though the functions and return statements

Please provide detailed steps or docs (if any) for debugging my programs

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: See [the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-13.htm?cp=1_1_0_11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Note especially paragraph 3.3: You have different options how to go the next step, going "into" functions or stepping over them.